# How to Close JInternalFrame when JButton click and show another JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jdesktoppane

For Example:

When `JButton1` click `JInternalFrame1` Show on the `JDesktopPane`
And when `JButton2` Click `JInternalFrame1` Close and `JInternalFrame2` Show on the `JDesktopPane`.

thx before

Edit: with code from comment

```
if (JInternalFrame1 == null) { 
    JInternalFrame1 = new FJInternalFrame(); 
    Desktop.add(JInternalFrame1); 
    JInternalFrame1.toFront();
} else { 
    JInternalFrame1.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like that difficult of a task. Can you please show the code you've tried?

Comment: if (JInternalFrame1 == null) {
                    JInternalFrame1 = new FJInternalFrame();
                    Desktop.add(JInternalFrame1);
                    JInternalFrame1.toFront();
                } else { JInternalFrame1.dispose();}

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. BTW - Why would you close the 1st internal frame as opposed to simply bringing the new internal frame in front of it?  Can you explain this to me in a way that would make sense to an end user?  It really seems like a single component using a `CardLayout` would work better.

Comment: maybe it's look like singleton method in continuous action, help me please

Comment: I try another way, but not work, can anybody help me?     public int Check() {
        JInternalFrame JIF[] = Desktop.getAllFrames();
        if (JIF.length > 0) {
            JInternalFrame1.dispose();
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

Comment: Tips: 1) Add @peeskillet  (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment. 2) Stop putting code in comments, where it is unreadable.  Instead [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20774628/edit). 3) *"look like singleton method in continuous action"*  Was that intended to answer my question?  It doesn't..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at this example. I created a custom JInternalFrame that has a different title every time you create a new frame. when you click on the button, a new one is created and the old one disapears

Here is the important code that may help you out. I add a new frame if the desktop size is equal to 0, other wise I remove the previous one, add a new frame, and revalidate

```
   button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (desktop.getAllFrames().length == 0) {
                desktop.add(new MyInternalFrame());

            } else {
                desktop.remove(0);
                desktop.add(new MyInternalFrame());
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
```

---

Here is the complete code. It's two different files.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class InternalFrameDemo1 extends JPanel {

    JDesktopPane desktop;
    JButton button;

    public InternalFrameDemo1() {
        desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        button = new JButton("Get Next Frame");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(desktop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (desktop.getAllFrames().length == 0) {
                    desktop.add(new MyInternalFrame());

                } else {
                    desktop.remove(0);
                    desktop.add(new MyInternalFrame());
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new InternalFrameDemo1());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

public class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    static int openFrameCount = 0;
    static final int xOffset = 30, yOffset = 30;

    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("Document #" + (++openFrameCount),
              true, //resizable
              true, //closable
              true, //maximizable
              true);//iconifiable

        setSize(300,300);
        setLocation(xOffset*openFrameCount, yOffset*openFrameCount);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]